# How to change Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense/context menu highlight color?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It seems I am not the only one complaining about [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditorprerelease/thread/2b463ad4-7c40-493b-82ce-1a407174744c). The yellow/gold color on top of the white background really makes me spend more time locating the highlight item. It may not be an issue for people who like using mouse. But I am a keyboard person and try to use mouse as little as possible. So this color is very annoying. Microsoft says it's not configurable in the reply. But I still hope someone can find a way to "hack" the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the add-in IntelliSence Presenter to make my IntelliSense look like this:
[image]

So, there are ways to change it, but it may involve downloading an add-in or writing your own.

Comment: +1, good to know. However it's a little overkill for my purpose. And this add-in doesn't help the context menu, I assume.

Comment: This is purely IntelliSense as far as I know. Try browsing the AddIn market.

Comment: And where can we get this add-in?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this extension: [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/changing-visual-studios-color-palette/)

But, be aware that each language can provide its own Intellisense UI, for extensibility. So, this may not solve your problem.

Comment: Individual languages generally don't provide their own intellisense presenters, only intellisense sources, so you are probably fairly safe.