# Visual Studio 2010 intellisense colors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, intellisense

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2010 intellisense]

Is it possible to change the color of intellisense in Visual Studio 2010. As you can see in this screen shot. Its virtualy impossible to see the **types** of the parameters because they're displyed with a white foreground colour on a grey background.

Comment: Didn't catch that you specifically wanted to change the color of the type in intellisense. I deleted my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Success at last. If you install the Productivity Power Tools addin (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

From version 10.0.10819.19 onwards you get a new option. Namely **Colorized Parameter Help** which allows you to customize the colors of the parameters and their types.

Excellent, now I can actually see the types of the parameters in the tooltips. Here is some description of the feature that can be found at the link above.

> *Colorized Parameter Help*
>
> This extension improves consistency with
>   the editor by applying syntax
>   highlighting to the contents of the
>   Parameter Help window for C# &VB.
>   Please note: Syntax highlighting
>   colors can be customized using the
>   display items prefixed with “Signature
>   Help” in the “Fonts and Colors” menu.
>
> *Colorized Parameter Help*
>
> There are now specific Fonts & Colors settings to allow you to
>   configure the display of items in
>   Parameter Help.  **This will allow
>   users with dark backgrounds to be able
>   to customize these to readable**.

Comment: What did you update to, I can't get it to work. That is in razor edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might be of use to you?

[How to change Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense/context menu highlight color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999407/how-to-change-visual-studio-2010-intellisense-context-menu-highlight-color)

Also the Theme Editor (Although not 100% if this can be used to modify intellisense)

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378

I know this isn't changing the intellisense but I really like this site too http://studiostyles.info

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same phase as yourself, changing the IDE colour schemes, and had the exact theme you did - its a lovely typeface and scheme is nice on the eyes.

The problem is whenever I had to go to someone else's screen or I needed them to help my with my code... they felt soo lost because they are used to the standard color convention in Visual Studio.

Eventually I've moved back to the default visual studio theme and prefer it - every code sample I read online (with colour style) read a lot more easier for me now. The only thing I have changed is the background from white to around #f5f5f5 .... it makes the white a little more easier on the eyes.